# Partial slideDown with jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, slidedown, jquery-hover

I have some buttons that have drawer menus and what I'd like to do is add a state so that when the user hovers over the button, the drawer bumps out slightly (maybe with a little wiggle/rubber-banding) so that they know that there's a drawer with more information.

I have the sliding working and a hover function set up, but I don't know how to implement a partial slideDown.

Any ideas?

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pN9ff/14/)**.

Code:

```
<div class="clause">
    <div class="icon"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/rTu40.png"/></div>
    <div class="label">Location</div>
    <div class="info">Midwest > Indiana, Kentucky; Southwest > Texas, Nevada, Utah; Pacific > California, Hawaii</div>        
</div>
<div class="drawer">Info 1<br/><br/></div> 
<div class="drawerBottom"></div>
```

---

```
$(".clause").click(function() {
    var tmp = $(this).next("div.drawer");
    if(tmp.is(":hidden"))
        tmp.slideDown('3s');
    else
        tmp.slideUp('3s');
});

$(".clause").hover(function() {

});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: hover takes two callbacks as arguments. One on `mouseenter` and one on `mouseleave`

Comment: Isn't hover just shorthand for those two arguments?

Comment: Hover takes two forms. With one callback, it calls the callback on `mouseEnter` and `mouseLeave`. With two callbacks, it calls the first one on `mouseEnter` and the second one on `mouseLeave`. Using the second form might be beneficial for you. http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this. The code is very dirty (I'm a beginner :P) so don't use it as it is.. clean it up a bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/VWQQ2/

```
$(".operator").click(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "OR") $(this).html("AND");
    else if ($(this).text() == "AND") $(this).html("NOT");
    else if ($(this).text() == "NOT") $(this).html("OR");
});

var tmp;

$(".clause").hover(function() {

    tmp = $(this).next("div.drawer");
    if (tmp.is(':hidden')) {
        tmp.height("1px");
        tmp.stop(true, true);
        tmp.slideDown('3s');
    }
},

function() {

    tmp = $(this).next("div.drawer");
    if (tmp.height() <= '1') {
        tmp.slideUp('3s');

    }
});


$(".clause").click(function() {
    tmp = $(this).next("div.drawer");
    tmp.stop(true, true);
    if (tmp.height() <= '1') {
        tmp.height('100%');
        var height = tmp.height();
        tmp.height('1px');
        tmp.animate({
            'height': height
        }, 500);
        state = 'open';
    }
    else if (tmp.height() > '2') {
        tmp.slideUp(500);
    }
});
```

Comment: That's basically what I want. How can I make the hover state faster though? I tried adjusting the seconds and it didn't work...